# My "answer" has been deleted as not helpful -- where can I leave a comment regarding this?

Tags: discussion, answers

The status the question described is in itself ridiculous after 17 years of existence of C++ exception handling. Sometimes ridicule is the best answer.

[Google C++ style guide's No-exceptions rule; STL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184115/google-c-style-guides-no-exceptions-rule-stl/19799315#19799315)

Ridicule here was not directed at the person who was asking the question, but at the unprofessional company which created the "coding rules" the question was referring to.

Comment: Link to the answer?

Comment: "Sometimes ridicule is the best answer." No, not on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Without context, we have *no idea* what you're talking about, and therefore can't be expected to help. Have downvoted; shall remove that if you edit to add context.

Comment: Usually ridicule is **not** a helpful answer. You can sometimes get away with it, provided you do a **really** good job at tickling the humour centers of those who vote. This is a fine line to walk and hard to pull off. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/100297) pulled it off. I managed it once. But **generally speaking** ridicule is not helpful and far from the best answer.

Comment: In what universe is that an answer?!?! That's barely even a constructive comment...

Comment: The question was caused by the ridiculous unprofessionalism of the company issuing these coding rules. Ridicule should manifest itself at every place where this coding rule is being mentioned. Otherwise one cannot be called a professional oneself!

Comment: Yeah, @user678269, I can see you've not been able to restrain yourself. [Your new answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184115/google-c-style-guides-no-exceptions-rule-stl/20768349#20768349) is really borderline - it's hard to see how it answers the questions asked - but you've probably gotten away with it.

Comment: I added another answer in which I elaborated more on why the possibility of this question is ridiculous after 17 years of exception handling. The answer should be in any c++ book printed after 1996 -- I think this predates STL.

Answer (score 9):

There are two constructive ways to deal with this:

- Flag the deleted answer for moderator attention. Describe why you disagree with the deletion, and why it should be undeleted.
- Write up a question here, on Meta. Look, you've done that already, cool. But you haven't linked to the answer, so *this* post is going nowhere. Add a link (users with at least 10k reputation can see deleted posts, when given a link), and describe why you think the deletion was unjustified.

In either case, you'd get a massive leg up if you took a shot at improving the answer first. It sounds like you dropped some ridicule on a user who you thought was asking a ridiculous question. Dial that back. Like Martijn says, you can pull it off, rarely, but most of the time, you end up sounding like Michael Richards. Write a real answer, help a real person out.

EDIT: You posted a link to the the answer that was deleted. But, small problem - it's not an answer. It doesn't attempt to resolve the problem asked. It was properly deleted, and it's hard to see how it could be edited into something acceptable here.

Comment: Where do I describe why I disagree with the deletion?

Comment: In the flag comment box, or in your post above, @user678269. Make sure you flag as "other (needs ♦ moderator attention)", which enables the box.

Comment: This answer is absoltely correct as an answer to this question. +1. That said, @user678269, I can tell you I can't see any moderator restoring that post.